# Android Studio ¿Como pasar datos a fragment dentro de View Pager?

Tags: android, android-fragment, viewpager

**Descripción:**

Tengo una actividad, la cual contiene un fragment (Lo llamaré **F.1**). Dentro de este fragment, hay otros 4 fragments (Sería un fragment tabbeado con view pager). El tema es que a **F.1** le llegan datos desde otra actividad, los cuales quiero llevar dentro de uno de esos 4 fragments.

**Pregunta:**

¿Como puedo pasar datos desde este **F.1** hacia adentro de uno de estos cuatro fragments que tiene adentro?

**A tener en cuenta:**

La funcionalidad de **F.1** respecto al cambio de fragments, es la misma que la que ofrece Android Studio cuando un programador crea una **Tabbed Activity**. Esto quiere decir que **F.1** tiene un adaptador, un model y un PlaceHolder (Como las tabbed activity por defecto).

**Adjunto el código del PlaceHolder**

```
public class PlaceholderFragment_perfil extends Fragment {

private model_perfil modelo;

public static Fragment newInstance(int index) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch(index){
        case 1:
            fragment = new fragment_informacion();
            break;

        case 2:
            fragment = new fragment_opiniones();
            break;

        case 3:
            fragment = new fragment_historial();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new fragment_balance();
            break;
    }

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    modelo = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(model_perfil.class);
    int index = 1;
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        index = getArguments().getInt("section_number");
    }
    modelo.setIndex(index);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);

    return root;
}
```

}

**Adjunto el código del fragment que está dentro de F.1 al cual le quiero pasar los datos (y que además está vacio)**

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_informacion, container, false);

return view;}
```

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

Comment: Tenés razón. Actualizé la pregunta con el código del place holder!

Comment: Te serviría mucho estudiar la comunicación entre fragmentos : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating?hl=es